# Supabase auth object is undefined

Tags: authentication, next.js, supabase

I am using Next.js 14 and Supabase Server Client for authentication.

I follow all instructions in Supabase [docs](https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/creating-a-client).

I am currently trying to implement an React Context for the current user.

This is my context use effect.

```
useEffect(() => {
        const fetchUser = async () => {
            const userData = await findUserSession();
            setUser(userData);
            setLoading(false);
        }
        fetchUser();
    }, [])
```

This is my server component

```
const supabase =  createClient();
    console.log(supabase);
    const { data : user, error: getError } = await supabase.auth.getUser();
```

The createClient is straight from the docs and when I console log the supabase object, I see the auth object inside.

I have tried using different versions of node or next but still an issue. This used to work properly, but does not work anymore.

Comment: You haven't shared the definition of `findUserSession()` method. You also haven't shared where you are getting `undefined` on.